# output is not desired. why no output for "gx+gy"?

Tags: c++

i made a class as A2dd and i want an output by printf from gx+gy but i dont see as the output. i want that the output which is from the class be shown in the console (since i use eclispe). but i just see "hello world".

where is the problem?

Main:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <stdio.h>
#include "A2dd.h"

using namespace std;

int main( )
{
A2dd(5,2);
int getsum();
cout << "hello world" << endl;

return 0;
}
```

header:

```
#ifndef A2DD_H_
#define A2DD_H_

class A2dd {

public:
int gx;
int gy;
A2dd(int x, int y);
int getsum();

};

#endif /* A2DD_H_ */
```

A2dd:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include "A2dd.h"
using namespace std;

A2dd::A2dd(int x, int y)
{
gx = x;
gy = y;
}

int A2dd::getsum()
{
 printf ("%d" , gx + gy);
 return 0;
}
```

Comment: You probably meant, in `main`,   `A2dd object(5,2); object.getsum();`

Comment: `getsum` is never called?

Comment: `int getsum();` in `main()` is a declaration, not a function call.  And it isn't a declaration of `A2dd::getsum()` either.

Comment: I think you need to read a good C++ introduction book. [Here is a good list of good C++ books.](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/388242/the-definitive-c-book-guide-and-list)

Comment: `int getsum();` <- This just means that there exists a function called `getsum` that takes no parameters and returns an integer. It has no connection whatsoever to the `A2dd` member function of the same name.

Answer (score 2):

`A2dd(5,2);` constructs an unnamed object of type `A2dd` and immediately destroys it. `int getsum();` declares but does not define a function named `getsum` that takes no arguments and returns `int`. Neither of those is what you want to do. Instead, try this:

```
A2dd value(5,2);
value.getsum();
```